# XSLT: moving a grouping html elements into section levels

Tags: html, xslt, grouping, saxon

I'm trying to write an XSLT that organizes an HTML file into different section levels depending on the header level. Here is my input:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>HEADER 1 CONTENT</h1>
  <p>Level 1 para</p>
  <p>Level 1 para</p>
  <p>Level 1 para</p>
  <p>Level 1 para</p>

  <h2>Header 2 CONTENT</h2>
  <p>Level 2 para</p>
  <p>Level 2 para</p>
  <p>Level 2 para</p>
  <p>Level 2 para</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm working with a fairly simple structure at the moment so this pattern will be constant for the time-being. I need an output like this...

```
<document> 
  <section level="1">
     <header1>Header 1 CONTENT</header1>
     <p>Level 1 para</p>
     <p>Level 1 para</p>
     <p>Level 1 para</p>
     <p>Level 1 para</p>
     <section level="2">
        <header2>Header 2 CONTENT</header2>
        <p>Level 2 para</p>
        <p>Level 2 para</p>
        <p>Level 2 para</p>
        <p>Level 2 para</p>
     </section>
  </section>
</document>
```

I had been working with this example: [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823561/xslt-grouping-following-siblings-with-same-name-and-same-attributes-causes-exce)

However, I cannot get it to do exactly what I need.

I'm using Saxon 9 to run the xslt within Oxygen for dev. I'll be using a cmd/bat file in production.  Still Saxon 9.  I'd like to handle up to 4 nested section levels if possible.

Any help is much appreciated!

I need to append onto this as I've encountered another stipulation.  I probably should have thought of this before.

I'm encountering the following code sample

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Level 1 para</p>
<p>Level 1 para</p>
<p>Level 1 para</p>
<p>Level 1 para</p>

<h1>Header 2 CONTENT</h1>
<p>Level 2 para</p>
<p>Level 2 para</p>
<p>Level 2 para</p>
<p>Level 2 para</p>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the `<p>` is a child of `<body>` while in my first snippet, `<p>` was always a child of a header level.  My desired result is the same as above except that when I encounter `<p>` as a child of `<body>`, it should be wrapped in `<section level="1">`.

```
<document> 
<section level="1">     
<p>Level 1 para</p>
<p>Level 1 para</p>
<p>Level 1 para</p>
<p>Level 1 para</p>
</section>
<section level="1">
<header1>Header 2 CONTENT</header1>
<p>Level 2 para</p>
<p>Level 2 para</p>
<p>Level 2 para</p>
<p>Level 2 para</p>
</section>
</document>
```

Comment: Jeff, consider to post the source code of the XML input as well as the source code of the corresponding output you want to create with Saxon 9, then we can help with the XSLT 2.0 code. And also explain how many levels you expect to handle (fixed number or arbitrary).

Comment: The source code for input and output should be displayed.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an XSLT 1.0 solution which isn't perceivably longer than the XSLT 2.0 solution of Martin Honnen. :)

Comment: After @Alejandro provided a more complicated XML source document, I have completely rewritten my solution and I think it desrves a look. One of the almost forgotten pearls of Jeni Tennison.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="elements" as="element()*"/>
    <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-starting-with="*[local-name() eq concat('h', $level)]">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::*[local-name() eq concat('h', $level)]">
          <section level="{$level}">
            <xsl:element name="header{$level}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., $level + 1)"/>
          </section>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/html">
    <document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="body"/>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(*, 1)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It should do what you asked for, although it does not stop at four nested levels but rather groups as long as it finds `h[n]` elements.

Answer (score 5):

**An XSLT 1.0 solution** (essentially borrowed by Jenni Tennison):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="html">
   <document><xsl:apply-templates/></document>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="body">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="h1" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:key name="next-headings" match="h6"
          use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[self::h1 or self::h2 or
                                               self::h3 or self::h4 or
                                               self::h5][1])" />
 <xsl:key name="next-headings" match="h5"
          use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[self::h1 or self::h2 or
                                               self::h3 or self::h4][1])" />
 <xsl:key name="next-headings" match="h4"
          use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[self::h1 or self::h2 or
                                               self::h3][1])" />
 <xsl:key name="next-headings" match="h3"
          use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[self::h1 or self::h2][1])" />
 <xsl:key name="next-headings" match="h2"
          use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::h1[1])" />

 <xsl:key name="immediate-nodes"
          match="node()[not(self::h1 | self::h2 | self::h3 | self::h4 |
                           self::h5 | self::h6)]"
          use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[self::h1 or self::h2 or
                                               self::h3 or self::h4 or
                                               self::h5 or self::h6][1])" />

 <xsl:template match="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | h6">
   <xsl:variable name="vLevel" select="substring-after(name(), 'h')" />
   <section level="{$vLevel}">
      <xsl:element name="header{$vLevel}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('immediate-nodes', generate-id())" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('next-headings', generate-id())" />
   </section>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*/node()" priority="-20">
   <xsl:copy-of select="." />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>1</h1>
        <p>1</p>
        <h2>1.1</h2>
        <p>2</p>
        <h3>1.1.1</h3>
        <p>3</p>
        <h2>1.2</h2>
        <p>4</p>
        <h1>2</h1>
        <p>5</p>
        <h2>2.1</h2>
        <p>6</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<document>
   <section level="1">
      <header1>1</header1>
      <p>1</p>
      <section level="2">
         <header2>1.1</header2>
         <p>2</p>
         <section level="3">
            <header3>1.1.1</header3>
            <p>3</p>
         </section>
      </section>
      <section level="2">
         <header2>1.2</header2>
         <p>4</p>
      </section>
   </section>
   <section level="1">
      <header1>2</header1>
      <p>5</p>
      <section level="2">
         <header2>2.1</header2>
         <p>6</p>
      </section>
   </section>
</document>
```

Comment: +1, good solution. Your `*[starts-with(name(),'h') and (floor(substring...` expression could be simplified to `*[translate(name(), 'h123456', '') = '']`. There are no elements in HTML that would generate false positives with that.

Comment: @Tomalak: Good comment -- I haven't worked closely with HTML for the last 10 years.

Comment: Check the result for `<body> <h1>1</h1> <p>1</p> <h2>1.1</h2> <p>2</p> <h3>1.1.1</h3> <p>3</p> <h2>1.2</h2> <p>4</p> <h1>2</h1> <p>5</p> <h2>2.1</h2> <p>6</p> </body>`

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks, I have provided a new solution now -- hope you'd like it :)

Comment: +1 Excellent example of the use of `xsl:key`. I've missed that feature.

Answer (score 3):

A more general grouping in XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kHeaderByPreceding"
             match="body/*[starts-with(name(),'h')]"
             use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*
                                 [starts-with(name(),'h')]
                                 [substring(name(current()),2)
                                   > substring(name(),2)][1])"/>
    <xsl:key name="kElementByPreceding"
             match="body/*[not(starts-with(name(),'h'))]"
             use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*
                                 [starts-with(name(),'h')][1])"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="copy"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="body">
        <document>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kHeaderByPreceding','')"/>
        </document>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="body/*[starts-with(name(),'h')]">
        <section level="{substring(name(),2)}">
            <xsl:element name="header{substring(name(),2)}">
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kElementByPreceding',
                                             generate-id())"
                                 mode="copy"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kHeaderByPreceding',
                                             generate-id())"/>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<document>
    <section level="1">
        <header1>HEADER 1 CONTENT</header1>
        <p>Level 1 para</p>
        <p>Level 1 para</p>
        <p>Level 1 para</p>
        <p>Level 1 para</p>
        <section level="2">
            <header2>Header 2 CONTENT</header2>
            <p>Level 2 para</p>
            <p>Level 2 para</p>
            <p>Level 2 para</p>
            <p>Level 2 para</p>
        </section>
    </section>
</document>
```

And with a more complex input sample like:

```
<body>
    <h1>1</h1>
    <p>1</p>
    <h2>1.1</h2>
    <p>2</p>
    <h3>1.1.1</h3>
    <p>3</p>
    <h2>1.2</h2>
    <p>4</p>
    <h1>2</h1>
    <p>5</p>
    <h2>2.1</h2>
    <p>6</p>
</body>
```

Output:

```
<document>
    <section level="1">
        <header1>1</header1>
        <p>1</p>
        <section level="2">
            <header2>1.1</header2>
            <p>2</p>
            <section level="3">
                <header3>1.1.1</header3>
                <p>3</p>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section level="2">
            <header2>1.2</header2>
            <p>4</p>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section level="1">
        <header1>2</header1>
        <p>5</p>
        <section level="2">
            <header2>2.1</header2>
            <p>6</p>
        </section>
    </section>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get something working for my addendum above. I added logic into the body template to test for header tags.  It may not work for every situation, but it is doing well for my task.

```
<xsl:template match="body">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="descendant::h1">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<section level="1">
<item>
<block ccm="yes" onbup="no" quickref="no" web="no">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</block>
</item>
</section>              
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>        
</xsl:template>
```