# Nested Headings

Tags: xml, xslt

is there any way to nest the headings with xlst, like I did it manually in this example?
I need to nest the headings h1 up to h3 and change each of them into the tag topic/title.

Old source code

```
<title>Text Title</title>
<h1>Text H1</h1>
<p>Text</p>
<h2>Text H2</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<h3>Text H3</h3>
<p>Text</p>
<h3>Text H3</h3>
<p>Text</p>
<h3>Text H3</h3>
<p>Text</p>
<h2>Text H2</h2>
<p>Text</p>
```

Nested new code

```
<topic>
  <title>Text Title</title>
  <topic>
    <title>Text H1</title>
    <p>Text</p>
    <topic>
      <title>Text H2</title>
      <p>Text</p>
      <topic>
        <title>Text H3</title>
        <p>Text</p>
      </topic>
      <topic>
        <title>Text H3</title>
        <p>Text</p>
      </topic>
      <topic>
        <title>Text H3</title>
        <p>Text</p>
      </topic>
    </topic>
    <topic>
      <title>Text H2</title>
      <p>Text</p>
    </topic>
  </topic>
</topic>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: A similar question was asked earlier, which might help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359677/need-help-nesting-siblings

Comment: Specifically, you need to group all H3 under H2 and then H2 under H1, so multiple groupings. In XSLT 1.0 this will involve Muenchian Method [http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html]. Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks for your help,
I tried it with your ideas, but I didn’t get it.
I found another way to do it with https://tools.oasis-open.org/version-control/browse/wsvn/xdi/DITA-OT1.5.4-ez/demo/h2d/h2d.xsl?sc=1
But it only transforms h1 and h2.
Do you still have a further approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="group" 
             match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'h')]" 
             use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = concat('h', number(substring-after(local-name(current()), 'h')) - 1)])" />

    <xsl:template match="body">
      <topic>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title|h1" />
      </topic>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'h')]">
        <topic>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="." /></title>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::p[1]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('group', generate-id())" />
        </topic>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This defines a key, called `group`, to group elements starting with `h` by their first preceding sibling that are an `h` element of the next number down. So, when you are positioned on a `h` element, you then use the key to get the nest elements.

Note this also assumes each `h` element is always followed by one, and only one, `p` element.