# Convert unstructured xml to structured

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've got an unstructured XML which has to be converted to a structured one. 
I am getting this from scientific pdf files parsed by apache tika and converted to xml by Parscit. The xml goes like this:

**INPUT**:

```
<algorithm>
    <sectionHeader> Section1 </sectionHeader>
    <BodyText>Text goes here</BodyText>
    <sectionHeader> Section2 </sectionHeader>
    <BodyText>Text goes here</BodyText>
    <subsectionHeader>Subsection</subsectionHeader>
    <BodyText>Text goes here</BodyText>
    <sectionHeader> Section1 </sectionHeader>
    <BodyText>Text goes here</BodyText>
</algorithm>
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
<algorithm>
    <sectionHeader> 
        <Text> Section1 </Text>
        <BodyText>Text goes here</BodyText>
    </sectionHeader>
    <sectionHeader> 
       <Text> Section2 </Text>
       <BodyText>Text goes here</BodyText>
    <subsectionHeader>
        <Text>Subsection</Text>
        <BodyText>Text goes here</BodyText>
    </subsectionHeader>
</sectionHeader>
<sectionHeader> 
    <text>Section3 </Text>
    <BodyText>Text goes here</BodyText>
</sectionHeader>
</algorithm>
```

I am able to do this using string builder and xpath in java. But it affects performance as i may have to process millions of documents. So is **xslt** a better approach?

Comment: What is your definition of "better"? Can you do the same using xslt? Is it more or less readable? Is it faster or not on your input? Only you can try and find answeres to these questions.

Comment: Why is `<sectionHeader> Section2 </sectionHeader><BodyText>Text goes here</BodyText>` in the result not showing up as `<sectionHeader><Text>Section 2</Text><BodyText>Text goes here</BodyText></sectionHeader>`? Should it even wrap the following subsectionHeader?

Comment: Oops! My mistake. Have corrected it.

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547271/xslt-moving-a-grouping-html-elements-into-section-levels/4547666#4547666 for an XSLT 2.0 example doing the `for-each-group group-starting-with` on a similar problem, depending on how many levels of sections and subsections you have your task may be simpler by simply wrapping two `for-each-group` or harder by identifying the elements constituting the current level's header elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/algorithm">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="sectionHeader">
            <sectionHeader> 
                <Text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </Text>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="subsectionHeader">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="self::subsectionHeader">
                            <subsectionHeader> 
                                <Text>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </Text>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(self::subsectionHeader)]"/>
                            </subsectionHeader> 
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(self::sectionHeader)]"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </sectionHeader>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```