# HTML to XML conversion using XSLT 2.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to convert a HTML file to XML format using **XSLT 2.0**. The HTML file contains only `<p>` tag with classes **h1**, **h2**, **h3**, . . .

```
<body>
    <p class='h1'>the fisr A</p>
    <p class='txt'>one</p>
    <p>tow</p>
    <p class='h2'>the sec B</p>
    <p class='txt'>theree</p>
    <p class='h2'>the sec sec B</p>
    <p class='txt'>the next text</p>
    <p class='h3'>the fisr C</p>
    <p class='txt'>four</p>
    <p class='txt'>five</p>
    <p class='h1'>the seccond A</p>
    <p class='txt'>the seccond txt</p>
    <p class='h2'>the second B</p>
    <p class='txt'>six</p>
    <p class='txt'>seven</p>
    <p class='h1'>the third A</p>
    <p class='txt'>eight</p>
    <p class='txt'>nine</p>    
</body>
```

**I need the XML output as shown below**

```
<book>
   <sectionA>
      <title>the fisr A</title>
      <p class="txt">one</p>
      <p>tow</p>
      <sectionB>
         <title>the sec B</title>
         <p class="txt">theree</p>
      </sectionB>
      <sectionB>
         <title>the sec sec B</title>
         <p class="txt">the next text</p>
         <sectionC>
            <title>the fisr C</title>
            <p class="txt">four</p>
            <p class="txt">five</p>
         </sectionC>
      </sectionB>
   </sectionA>
   <sectionA>
      <title>the seccond A</title>
      <p class="txt">the seccond txt</p>
      <sectionB>
         <title>the second B</title>
         <p class="txt">six</p>
         <p class="txt">seven</p>
      </sectionB>
   </sectionA>
   <sectionA>
      <title>the third A</title>
      <p class="txt">eight</p>
      <p class="txt">nine</p>
   </sectionA>
</book>
```

Can anyone help me to get the desired output?

Comment: Have a look at the 3rd example here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples

Comment: Go for it with `<xsl:for-each-group>` and implement your logic. This harsh comment is because of your lack of "try it on your own" and "let the community code it for me". SO is for help, not for coding requests.

Comment: I try using for-each-group but I cant able to bring the expected output

Comment: See similar questions with existing answers, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547271/xslt-moving-a-grouping-html-elements-into-section-levels.

Comment: It gives necessary inputs but I never get final requirements.

Comment: @Reegan show your xslt code and someone might be able to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">        
    <xsl:template match="body">
        <book>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with="p[@class='h1']">
                <sectionA>
                    <title>
                        <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                    </title>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="p[@class='h2']">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="self::p[@class='h2']">
                                <sectionB>
                                    <title>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                                    </title>
                                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="p[@class='h3']">
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="self::p[@class='h3']">
                                                <sectionC>
                                                    <title>
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                                                    </title>
                                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."></xsl:apply-templates>
                                                </sectionC>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"></xsl:apply-templates>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                                </sectionB>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"></xsl:apply-templates>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>

                </sectionA>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </book>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>      <!-- added by edit -->
```