# Wrapping the content under section based on head-title - XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a problem in wrapping the content that is present between the titles.

For example I have an `XML` structure as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <title1>This is first-level head</title1>
    <p>first paragraph...</p>
    <p>second paragraph...</p>
    <p>so on...</p>
    <title2>This is second-level head</title2>
    <p>first paragraph under level-2 nesting</p>
    <p>second paragraph..</p>
    <p>so on...</p>
    <title1>This is first-level head</title1>
    <p>first paragraph...</p>
    <p>second paragraph...</p>
    <p>so on...</p>
    <title1>This is first-level head</title1>
    <p>first paragraph...</p>
    <p>second paragraph...</p>
    <p>so on...</p>
</root>
```

And I want it to be transformed as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <section>
        <title>This is first-level head</title>
        <p>first paragraph...</p>
        <p>second paragraph...</p>
        <p>so on...</p>
        <section>
            <title>This is second-level head</title>
            <p>first paragraph under level-2 nesting</p>
            <p>second paragraph..</p>
            <p>so on...</p>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>This is first-level head</title>
        <p>first paragraph...</p>
        <p>second paragraph...</p>
        <p>so on...</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>This is first-level head</title>
        <p>first paragraph...</p>
        <p>second paragraph...</p>
        <p>so on...</p>
    </section>
</root>
```

Like that, with deep-level nesting structure.

Help me out, in producing the below structured output.
Would be much appreciated if we wont use for-each loop, because the content is huge and will effect the performance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4547666/252228 for a solution to a similar problem, the elements are named `h1` instead of `title1` but you can adapt that.

Comment: Thanks Martin Honnen