# Need to create sublist format for paras with out root elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to generate sublist for specific

Mysource

```
<p class="l1">   (a)<tab/>blah blah</p>
<p class="l1">   (b)<tab/>blah blah</p>
<p class="l1">   (c)<tab/>blah blah</p>
<p class="l2">   (i)<tab/>blah blah</p>
<p class="l2">   (ii)<tab/>blah blah</p>
<p class="l2">   (iii)<tab/>blah blah</p>
<p class="l2">   (iv)<tab/>blah blah</p>
```

xslt used:

```
<xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='l1']" priority="122">
    <item num="{replace(node()[1], '^\s+', '')}">
      <para><xsl:apply-templates select="node()[position() gt 2]"/></para>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='l2']" priority="122">
    <item num="{replace(node()[1], '^\s+', '')}">
      <para><xsl:apply-templates select="node()[position() gt 2]"/></para>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='l3']" priority="122">
    <item num="{replace(node()[1], '^\s+', '')}">
      <para><xsl:apply-templates select="node()[position() gt 2]"/></para>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
```

output i am getting with out sublist format:

```
<item num="(a)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
<item num="(b)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
<item num="(c)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
<item num="(i)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
<item num="(ii)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
<item num="(iii)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
<item num="(iv)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
```

but i want output as sublist format as like below:

```
<orderedlist type="manual">
<item num="(a)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
<item num="(b)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
<item num="(c)"><para>blah blah</para>
<orderedlist type="manual">
<item num="(i)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
<item num="(ii)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
<item num="(iii)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
<item num="(iv)"><para>blah blah</para></item>
</orderedlist>
</item>
</orderedlist>
```

Please suggest me!

Comment: An example is not enough. Please add an explanation of the required logic in words.

Comment: Please show some context, usually the input to XSLT is a well-formed XML document where those `p` elements would have some container element. If you have some XSLT (2.0?) where you have a sequence of those `p` elements then show us that context. In general it sounds like a recursive grouping problem similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547271/xslt-moving-a-grouping-html-elements-into-section-levels.