# How to transform flat xml to hierarchical one (xslt 1.0)

Tags: xml, xslt

Input: I have a following xml

```
<document>
<sec1>heading (depth 1)</sec1>
<p>body</p>
<sec1>heading (depth 1)</sec1>
<sec2>heading (depth 2)</sec2>
<p>body</p>
<sec1>heading (depth 1)</sec1>
<sec2>heading (depth 2)</sec2>
<sec3>heading (depth 3)</sec3>
<p>body</p>
</document>
```

Output: And following is a structure I want to change into using xslt 1.0

```
<document>
    <sec1 id=001>
        <title>Heading (depth 1)</title>
            <p>body</p>
    </sec1>
    <sec1 id=002>
        <title>Heading (depth 1)</title>
            <sec2 id=002-1>
                 <title>Heading (depth 2)</title>
                     <p>body</p>
            </sec2>
    </sec1>
    <sec1 id=003>
        <title>Heading (depth 1)</title>
            <sec2 id=003-1>
                 <title>Heading (depth 2)</title>
                     <sec3 id=003-1-1>
                         <title>Heading (depth 3)</title>
                              <p>body</p>
                     </sec3>
            </sec2>
    </sec1>
</document>
```

What code should I write? It is so tricky to make multiple hierarchical xml.

Comment: If you really need to solve that with XSLT 1, then see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4548585/252228 to a similar question.

Comment: I found an answer thanks to you. Thank you very much.