# XSLT sort with attribute value and creating Table of Content (TOC)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a question about creating TOC with the sample XML file the challenge I face is to get the sorting and ordering of the XML in a nested way with proper TOC.

**Here is my XML**

```
<root>
    <Statute>

        <Body>
            <Heading level="1">
                <TitleText>Title</TitleText>
            </Heading>
            <Section>lorem</Section>
            <Heading level="1"><Label>PART 1</Label>
                <TitleText>part1 data</TitleText>
            </Heading>
            <Heading level="2">
                <TitleText>subpart</TitleText>
            </Heading>
            <Section>lorem</Section>
            <Heading level="3">
                <TitleText>sub-subpart</TitleText>
            </Heading>
            <Section>lorem</Section>
            <Heading level="3">
                <TitleText>sub-subpart</TitleText>
            </Heading>
            <Section>lorem</Section>
        </Body>
    </Statute>
</root>
```

This is the Output I am looking for

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="main">
         <div class="ltTOCl1"><a href="id_d1e4.html">Title</a></div>
         <div class="ltTOCl1"><a href="id_d1e7.html">PART1</a></div>
         <div class="ltTOCl2"><a href="id_d1e10.html">subpart</a></div>
         <div class="ltTOCl3"><a href="id_d1e13.html">sub-subpart</a></div>
         <div class="ltTOCl3"><a href="id_d1e16.html">sub-subpart</a></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Here is the XSLT**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwMZc.png)

Comment: That rather seems to require a recursive use of  `for-each-group select="Heading" group-starting-with="Heading[@level = $level]"`, where on each recursive call you increment the `$level`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4547666/252228 is one example, only you seem to want to keep a flat structure so use the given recursive scheme but don't nest the recursive call in the result elements you create.

Comment: It's not clear how the output should be in case the levels were not only increasing.